# Using SQL Server SDK with SQL Server Compact Edition Database

Tags: sql-server, sdk, sql-server-ce, smo

I've been looking into the following CodeProject article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CreateSQLDV.aspx

and I've been trying to figure out if I can get this to work both with standard SQL Server databases, as well as SQL Server CE databases.

I can create the Database object for a standard db that's on my server:

```
Server dbServer = new Server("myserver.com");
Database database = dbServer.Databases["MyDB"];
```

But I'm having my issues when in trying to create the object for a local, compact edition database:

```
Server dbServer = new Server("C:\PathToDb\MyDb.sdf");
Database database = dbServer.Databases["MyDB"];
```

I know that in most cases there isn't much overlap between SQL Server and SQL Server CE, but considering this is the SQL Server SDKs, and SQL Server Management Studio can connect to compact edition databases, I'm thinking there must be some way I'm overlooking...

Answer (score 0):

There is no SMO for SQL Server Compact, to create databases, you can use the SqlCeEngine object. For othr scripting purposes, you can use my scripting API, http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com